# matching 2 column in different tables and replace one of them with a 3rd column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table dbo.Patient with theses columns

```
PatientID | Name | DOB
```

and another table dbo.Studies with theses columns

```
PatientID | AccessionNumber
```

PatientId are common between the 2 tables but i want to create a query to replace PAtientID in Patient table by AccessionNumber in studies Table after matching PatientID between the 2 tables.

How can I do it ?

Comment: please provide sample data and output

Comment: why do you need to match the patientID in patients? wouldn't `UPDATE studies SET AsseccionNumber=? WHERE PatientID=?` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
update Patient 
set Patient.PatientId =  Studies.AccessionNumber 
from Patient inner join Studies
on Patient.PatientId =  Studies.PatientId;
```